# Multiple media queries are not working as expected

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have multiple media queries, but only first media works.

so the only media working is  (min-width: 4100px)  AND (max-width: 8000px)

and the other as if they are not in the stylesheet file.

how to solve this problem ?

```
/*phone*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 5000px)  AND (max-width: 8000px) {

    body {

        font-size: 65px;
    }

    header {
        height: 182px;
    }

    #header_photo {
        width: 460px !important;
        height: 180px;
    }

    td, th {
        padding: 50px 85px;
    }

    .status_table {
        padding: 110px;
    }

    .end_table {
        padding: 110px;
    }

    .total-sms, .total_calls, .tot_sh {
        padding: 56px;
    }

    .active_login {
        padding: 15px 10px 10px
    }

    .second_section {
        margin-top: 295px;
    }

    .pie_chart_main {
        margin-left: 890px;
    }

    .pie_chart {
        width: 2600px;
        height: 1650px;
    }

    text {
        font-size: 55px;
    }

    circle.on:after {
        content: 'r="20"';
        width: 100px;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .date {
        margin-left: 1800px;
        font-size: 60px;
    }

    .num_style {
        font-size: 90px;
    }
}

​

@media only screen and (min-width: 2250px) and (max-width: 4000px) {

    body {

        font-size: 30px;
    }

    td, th {
        padding: 20px 35px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .status_table {
        padding: 50px;
    }

    .end_table {
        padding: 50px;
    }

    .total-sms, .total_calls, .tot_sh {
        padding: 36px;
    }

    .active_login {
        padding: 15px 10px 10px
    }

    .second_section {
        margin-top: 155px;
    }

    .pie_chart_main {
        margin-left: 290px;
    }

    .pie_chart {
        width: 1300px !important;
        height: 850px !important;
    }

    text {
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    circle.on:after {
        content: 'r="20"';
        width: 100px;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .date {
        margin-left: 900px;
        font-size: 34px;
    }
}

​

@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) and (max-width: 2200px) {

    body {
        font-size: 19px;
    }

    td, th {
        padding: 10px 18px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .status_table {
        padding: 23px;
    }

    .end_table {
        padding: 23px;
    }

    .total-sms, .total_calls, .tot_sh {
        padding: 15px;
    }

    .active_login {
        padding: 15px 10px 10px
    }

    .second_section {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .pie_chart_main {
        margin-left: 130px;
    }

    .pie_chart {
        width: 900px;
        height: 550px;
    }

    .date {
        margin-left: 500px;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

}

​
```

Comment: Add the complete CSS (or check it using validator). It's probably a missing closing bracket somewhere.

Comment: A side point, but why are you ignoring resolutions between 4001 and 4999 wide and between 2201 and 2249?

Comment: I added the css

Comment: because I want it to work on specific screens only

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the stray character you have between each media query. If you check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/wmc1x2e9/), you'll see it as *a dot with a red background*.

Below sample shows it works, though I changed the width's values so one can see it when resizing the browser on a standard screen.

```css
/*phone*/

body {
  background: gray;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 800px)  AND (max-width: 1000px) {

    body {
        background: green;
    }
  
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 750px) {

    body {
        background: yellow;
    }
  
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px) {

    body {
        background: red;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ohhh I've never known such thing. it's really weird issue. I also installed "Zero Width Characters locator"  it's really helpful. Thank a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should have two colons before 'after' not one.

```
circle.on::after
```

On the 13th rule, first section. And again near the end of the second section.

Comment: I always use one colon. Thanks for the tip, but I don't think that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: You always use one colon? It's a standard, not a personal preference. It requires two. Other selectors use one colon, those use two.

Comment: Thank you I will do that from now and on

Comment: @jack You can use it with 1 colon, which is CSS2 syntax, though the recommended is with 2 colon, unless you target older browsers, which need 1